# Quiero estar en bucle WHILE hasta dejar de escribir en un Char en C++

Tags: c++, while, bucles

Quiero leer un texto de manera infinita hasta dejar de escribir, e ir contando las vocales. Pero dejo de escribir y no me sale del bucle WHILE, ¿por qué?
Gracias por la ayuda :) Aquí dejo el código:

```
unsigned aCnt = 0, eCnt = 0, iCnt = 0, oCnt = 0, uCnt = 0;
char ch;
std::cout << "Write something: " << std::endl;

while (std::cin >> ch) {
    switch (ch) {
    case 'a':
        ++aCnt;
        break;
    case 'e':
        ++eCnt;
        break;
    case 'i':
        ++iCnt;
        break;
    case 'o':
        ++oCnt;
        break;
    case 'u':
        ++uCnt;
        break;
    }
}
std::cout << "Number of vowel a: " << aCnt << '\n'
    << "Number of vowel e: " << eCnt << '\n'
    << "Number of vowel i: " << iCnt << '\n'
    << "Number of vowel o: " << oCnt << '\n'
    << "Number of vowel u: " << uCnt << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::cin` se queda esperando a recibir un valor por la entrada estándar. Al tener la instrucción como condición del bucle estas esperando un valor de entrada de forma infinita. Te sugiero que si quieres parar de leer utilices una variable para controlar el bucle o alguna cadena de entrada para parar el bucle por ejemplo:

```
Leer = true;
while (Leer)
{
    char c; 
    std::cin >> c;

    if (c == 'Q' || c == 'q')
    {
        Leer= false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::cin >>
```

Al leer de un *stream*, si no hay nada que leer el programa se bloquea hasta que hay algo que leer o el *stream* se cierra. El SO proporciona los datos (desde entrada estandar, de un fichero, de la red...).

No hay un concepto de "dejar de escribir". Lo cual es una suerte, porque a la velocidad a la que trabaja un ordenador, tiene tiempo de sobra para notar que has "dejado de escribir" por más rápido que teclees.

Lo que puedes hacer es, por ejemplo, cerrar la salida estándar (CTRL+Z en consola de Windows, CTRL + D en Windows) que detectas cuando `cin.eof()` devuelve `true`

Aparte de eso, hay formas de hacer programas que detecten el "dejar de escribir":

- en lugar de trabajar con STDIN, tu programa detecta las teclas pulsadas y, con un temporizador, detectan cuando han pasado X segundos desde la última tecla pulsada. El problema es que tendrás que procesar todas las teclas con tu programa, en lugar de disponer de un *stream* que ya te da el texto directamente, y es bastante más complicado.
- tienes un *thread* que lee del STDIN y otro *thread* con un *watchdog*. Cada vez que lees de STDIN, reseteas una variable. Si pasa mucho tiempo sin que se resetee, el *watchdog* termina el programa.